# Error while executing Oracle stored procedure in SSRS: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]

I am trying to execute simple oracle stored procedure from SSRS in Visual studio 2012.

I get this error:

> An error occurred while executing the query.ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SPPARAMETERTEST'ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:PL/SQL: Statement ignored (Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer)

Stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE spParameterTest (Results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
IS    
BEGIN    

  OPEN Results FOR           
    SELECT *          FROM CA_CASE;
--END spParameterTest;        
END spParameterTest;
```

Environment:

- Oracle Client: 11.2
- Server: 12c
- Visual Studio 2012

Please let me know whats the issue with this stored procedure or any thing needs to be installed on SSRS to execute Oracle stored procedure

Comment: I presume double `end`s are typo?

Comment: @Littlefoot - sorry its typo error.its only one end

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the VS2017 and ODAC tools and the issue got fixed.